# Creating a thread which acquires a mutex before the calling thread in C++0x

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have the following situation

```
std::mutex m;

void t() {
    //lock the mutex m here
}

main() {
    //create thread t here
    //lock the mutex m here
}
```

I would like the thread `t()` to acquire the mutex before `main()` does, how can I obtain this behaviour using the threading functions provided by C++11?

Putting simply an `std::lock_guard` inside `main()` and `t()` would not work because it can take a bit before the thread is spawned, an so the mutex can be locked by `main()`.

Comment: I'm a little worried that you intend to use this as an alternative to `join` and/or condition variables. If your purpose here is to wait until the thread is done, or until it has completed some operation, this is not the appropriate way to do that.

Comment: No, join is not related to the real problem. Anyway from the simplified description I gave your concern is correct.

Comment: Awesome. Just checking.

Comment: Not sure about conditional variables, I will think about that

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the conditional variable that Sneftel mentioned in the comment section, and a somewhat similar solution to the one provided by Angew:

One possible solution:

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
bool threadIsReady = false; //bool should be fine in this case

void t() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> g(m);
    threadIsReady = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}


int main() {
    std::thread th(t);

    //if main locks the mutex first, it will have to wait until threadIsReady becomes true
    //if main locks the mutex later, wait will do nothing since threadIsReady would have already been true
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> g(m);
    cv.wait(g, [] {return threadIsReady; });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick & dirty way to achieve this effect:

```
std::atomic<bool> threadIsReady{false};

void t()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
  threadIsReady = true;
}

main()
{
  std::thread th(t);
  while (!threadIsReady) {}
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
}
```

Comment: Might as well use a condition var. In a worst scenario, having the parent spinning may stop the child from starting.

Comment: @GemTaylor True indeed; however, since I rarely program mutlithreaded stuff, I'd have to look up the syntax etc. I could do the atomic off the top of my head, so I used that.

Comment: @GemTaylor why the mutex if there is already an atomic value?

Comment: @GemTaylor are you referring to another situation or there are problem with the codes of Angew? Because I can't see how it could get wrong

Comment: @Nisba With "true indeed", I was referring to a conditional variable being better. I don't think it would be legal for a threading implementation to prevent the thread from starting by the main one's spinning.

Comment: If you only have one processor, having your main thread spinning in not obviously multithreaded code rather than giving up its timeslice means you could be waiting a long time for the child process to get started.